# Lossy to Loss less Audio format file conversion, can the lost frequencies can come back to life so precisely?

Tags: audio-streaming, audio-processing

I have heard lossy formats like mp3 , oga and all can be converted to lossless like flac, aiff, wav.
Is it really possible and how is it done???

Comment: No.  The formats may be converted from lossless to lossy to lossless ad nauseum, but the quality is only as good as the last lossy source.

Comment: So what formats do Spotify and Deezer play.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a lossy codec like MP3, the extra fidelity is lost at the time of encoding.  Once it's lost, it's never coming back.  (If this were possible, lossy codecs wouldn't be lossy in the first place!)

You can decode that stream and store it in a lossless format, but the damage is already done so you're just wasting disk space if you do this.

Comment: I am not doing this, I need this for my project. And yea, lossy codec wouldn't be lossy in the first place.
Please tell me any place n internet to get authentic lossless wav files (if you know any place to download lossless wav music albums, it would be christmas!!)

Comment: @AbhilashMohapatra You can buy FLAC or WAV files from most any online music store.  Personally, I usually find it cheaper to buy the CD and rip it myself.  JunoDownload, 7Digital, HD Tracks, etc., all have high quality digital files you can buy.